# Truncating a string after first \n

Tags: java, android, regex

I am not very good at regex etc. I need to get the remaining string after the first \n in counter in a string.

Example:

```
going.\nTest found at 241.
```

So i wanna return `Test found at 241.`

Maybe there is a very easy solution but i cant figure it out.

Comment: You just need to find the index of '\n' if present in the string and take a substring from there till the end. You don't need regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String ss="going.\nTest found at 241.";
    System.out.println(ss.substring(ss.indexOf("\n")+1));
```

`string.indexIf(STR)` will return you the index of first occurrence of that string (STR)

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
String s = "going.\nTest found at 241.";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("\n") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
String s =  "going.\nTest found at 241";
String[] parts = s.split("\n");
if(parts.length==2) {
 //do something with parts[1];
}
```

Comment: in fact String.split(java.lang.String) uses a regex. And you can directly use String.split(java.lang.String;I), with the limit as second parameter

Answer (score 0):

In such easy case, simply use `myString.indexOf('\n')` to find the position of your `\n` character (if it exists), then use `substring` to remove what is before this position.

Comment: This was precisely the thing i was looking for! Thank you very much(I knew there was a simple solution, just couldnt for the love of god figure it out...)

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("\n")+1,str.length());
```

Comment: it's just one of N ways to get the result

Comment: but still, you do not need second parameter.